# Communicating between two Raspberry Pi's

Tags: gpio, web-server, sockets

I'm working on a project that uses two Raspberry Pi's.

The idea is that I have one running at home, which stores all the files that I need to execute. I will take the other Raspberry Pi along to work to demonstrate something. For example:

I'm planning to create a web interface (Which is stored at home with PuTTY connections from the outside). The other Raspberry pi will be at the place I work with and the idea is that I can open a browser, type in the url of my server, push a button and it will send a signal to the second Pi (stored at work) which will trigger a set of LEDS.

I hope that make sense..

Questions:

1) Would Sockets be an ideal solution for the above?

2) Which Pi would be the Socket server? Since the Pi that is stored at my work is essentially "listening" out for a signal whereas the Pi stored at home is just sending the signal.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [WebIOPi](http://code.google.com/p/webiopi/):

> WebIOPi is a REST framework and a webapp which allows you to control your Raspberry Pi's GPIO.

Using this you can control all the GPIO directions and Values from the browser graphically. Basically they built this on Rest framework.

Comment: Hi- If you just want to add a short answer please use comments. Otherwise try and expand your answer a bit. How to install? an example, picture, short tutorial. It is good answer it just needs more content. Thanks +1

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks for your kind suggestion, sure I will follow from next answers. Thanks again :)

Comment: Although I've helped edit this to be a little clearer, I fail to see how this answers the original question.

Comment: @MarkBooth Thanks for the edit, I agree my answer not suits for questions he asked. But for idea he mentioned.